# throwing int' object is not iterable in python when trying to pull particular value?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below code in my python script which I am using to get the values of component field of JIRA issue and whatever the component/s field are having the values the below logic is reading that and if the value matches with R Ciapara or CTX then it is doing the next task which is basically removing the text part and getting only numeric value from that String which is 1.3 and 1.2 in below case.After that I am making it unique if two values are same for e.g R Ciapara 1.3 (Released),R Ciapara 1.3.In this case it will give me 1.3,1.3 then I am making it 4.3

Example of Component/s Field is

```
Component/s: M Nx, M CitLx, R Ciapara 1.3 (Released), CTX 1.2
```

Logic in the python script:

```
def Test(Host, issue):


  allModules = []                                      

  componentmatch = 0 
  for version in issue["fields"]["components"]:
    cacheData = json.dumps(version)
    jsonToPython = json.loads(cacheData)
    print jsonToPython
    #componentmatch = 0 
    if jsonToPython['name'][:10] == "R Ciapara " or version["name"][:4] == "CTX ":
      componentmatch += 1
      componentmatch = re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+", jsonToPython['name'])
    if componentmatch:
      allModules.append(componentmatch[0])
      d={i for i in allModules}
      p=list(d)

  matchcomp = ("[{}]".format(", ".join(p)))
  return matchcomp
```

Error I am getting is below "int' object is not iterable" :

```
Processing TPT-3
R Ciapara 4.3 (Released)
Ciapara 1.4.90.0
{u'self': u'https://test/rest/api/2/component/730', u'id': u'730', u'name': u'M Nx'}
{u'self': u'https://test/rest/api/2/component/73', u'id': u'73', u'name': u'M CitLx'}
{u'self': u'https://test/rest/api/2/component/1', u'id': u'1', u'name': u'R Ciapara 1.3 (Released)'}
[1.3]
[1.4, 1.2]
Processing TPT-2
R Ciapara 1.3(U1)
Ciapara 1.4.3.4
{u'self': u'https://test/rest/api/2/component/7', u'id': u'7', u'name': u'R Ciapara 1.3(U1)'}
[1.3]
[1.4]
Processing TPT-1
R Ciapara 1.4
Ciapara 1.4.73.4
{u'self': u'https://test/rest/api/2/component/733', u'id': u'733', u'name': u'R Ciapara 1.4'}
{u'self': u'https://test/rest/api/2/component/7335', u'id': u'7335', u'name': u'R Ciapara 1.4(U1)'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Not able to understand what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `1` to `componentmatch` here:

```
componentmatch += 1
```

and then re-assigning `componentmatch` to the returned output of `re.findall()`, which returns a list of strings here:

```
componentmatch = re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+", jsonToPython['name'])
```

Then once you enter this `if` statement again:

```
if jsonToPython['name'][:10] == "R Ciapara " or version["name"][:4] == "CTX ":
```

Now you are attempting to add `1` again to a list of strings, which will throw the following error:

```
componentmatch += 1 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

You are attempting to add an integer to a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Now I changed my logic and it works

```
  allModules = []                                      

  Fixversionmatch = 0  
  for version in issue["fields"]["fixVersions"]:
    if version['name'][:8] == "Ciapara " or version["name"][:4] == "CTX ":  
      cacheData = json.dumps(version)
      jsonToPython = json.loads(cacheData)    
      Fixversionmatch = re.findall(r"(\d+\.\d+)\.\d+\.\d+", jsonToPython['name'])
    if Fixversionmatch:
      allModules.append(Fixversionmatch[0])
      d={i for i in allModules}
      p=list(d)


  matchFix = ("[{}]".format(", ".join(p)))
  return matchFix
```